# Android HttpClient authentication always returns 401 code

Tags: android, authentication, post, httpclient

I'm trying to post the player score on-line using HTTP authentication but the response is always 401 (Unauthorized), although I'm pretty sure the username and password is correct. What am I doing wrong?

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
Credentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "passsword");
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope("http://myurl.com/score.php", 80), creds);

try {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://myurl.com/score.php");

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);   
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("score", points));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        throw new Exception();
    }

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    //
} catch (IOException e) {
    //
} catch (Exception e) {
    //
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved the problem. I'm using

```
new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT) // works
```

instead of the previous

```
new AuthScope("http://myurl.com/score.php", 80) // error
```

Comment: Great! You can accept your own answer to the question so it shows up as answered :)

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. This helped me solve my problem :-)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for SSL connections.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
new AuthScope("myurl.com", 80);
```

Comment: Please try to provide some explanation and/or links with your answers to explain *why* your solution should work.