# Load Url without launching android browser

Tags: android

How to load url without launching android browser?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is your goal? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I've created URL with params, once i clicked on submit button the data should stored on server? If i copy and paste the url in browser the data gets updated on server? but i dont't want to do like this.

Comment: You can for example use HTTP POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(YOUR URL COMES HERE);
    String responseBody;

    try {
        BasicHttpResponse response = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.w("com.name.pkg", e);
        return 0;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("com.name.pkg", e);
        return 0;
    }
       return 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi buddy, its getting 401 unauthorized. Authorization requrired. How to pass username and password?

Comment: You get the same message if you try to visit the URL in a web browser?

Comment: hmm, try to check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283996/android-httpclient-authentication-always-returns-401-code

Answer (score 0):

Use **WebView** in your app. Try below tutorial if you don't know how to use WebView.

[Android WebView Demo](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/58.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class NonBrowserLaunchingURLLoader {
    public void loadURL(String url) {
        // Don't launch the android browser here.
    }
}
```