# Android: post to a password protected server

Tags: android, apache, http, webserver, mime4j

I am trying to send information from my Android device to my php server. I followed this tutorial (http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/04/android-http-client.html), but then realized there is nowhere to specify my useID and password to log into the server. a lot of search but could not get anywhere. I am new to both Android and Apache. Please advice, thanks.

Comment: use case: if I log in from winscp to my php server, I need to enter user id and password. but if I make a httppost call (to execute a .php script located on my server) from my android program, I do not really need the previous user id and password as long as I know the exact url to that php script. is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i have to learn to ask the right question or enter the right words to search. i finally found with this post and got my answer.
[Android HttpClient authentication always returns 401 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283996/android-httpclient-authentication-always-returns-401-code)