# Http Authentication via Android

Tags: android, http, authentication, httpclient, http-status-code-401

I currently try to make an authentication on Android the same way I'm doing it with Postman [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qRjC.jpg).

I followed some examples everywhere on the Internet and I came up with this code :

```
 protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

        try{
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_username", mylogin));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_password", mypassword));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
            StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                throw new Exception("Status Error CODE : " + status.getStatusCode());
            }

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream in = entity.getContent();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int readCount;
            while ((readCount = in.read(buff)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(buff, 0, readCount);
            }
            return new String (out.toByteArray());
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I keep getting an Error 401 and I don't understand why. Is there anything that I'm not seeing ?

By the way I also try to use its [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283996/android-httpclient-authentication-always-returns-401-code) but didn't get better.

Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution, the problem wasn't from Android but from the server under Symphony. Symphony needed to create a session before accepting requests.